# Angular ui bootstrap modal won't animate after bower install

Tags: angularjs, bower, angular-bootstrap

I ran a bower install and have some sort of dependency conflict, everything works and the site loads fine with no errors but the bootstrap modals won't animate.  animate is set to true.  Any tips for debugging this would be appreciated.

```
{
"name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.3",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "angular-resource": "1.4.3",
    "angular-cookies": "1.4.3",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.4.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "ng-clip": "*",
    "angular-scroll-glue": "~2.0.6",
    "ng-timeago": "*",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.2",
    "ng-file-upload-shim": "~6.2.1",
    "bootstrap-carousel-swipe": "*",
    "jquery.maskedinput": "~1.4.1",
    "ngAutocomplete": "~1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.4.3",
    "angular-scenario": "1.4.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": ">1.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to install angular-animate too

Comment: maybe you didn't inject 'ngAnimate' on your modules?
something like this?
angular.module('yourApp', ['ngAnimate']);

Comment: looks like you need to use Angular 1.4.5+ for the modal's to support animation.  Thanks for the feedback though

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is only supported in Angular 1.4.5 +.